# How to get event onkeyup in input id two using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get event onkeyup in input `id="two"` using javascript?

I not permission to edit in function `test_1_fn()` and input `id="one"`

So, how can i edit in input `id="two"` or function `test_2_fn()` to get value from input `id="two"` for `alert` as a onkeyup ?

Remark : User can fill text into input `id="one"` only.

```html
<input id="one" onkeyup="test_1_fn()"><br>
<script>
    function test_1_fn() {
        var one_val = document.getElementById("one").value;
        document.getElementById("two").value = one_val;
    }
</script>
<input id="two" onkeyup="test_2_fn()"><br>
<script>
    function test_2_fn() {
        var two_val = document.getElementById("two").value;
        alert(two_val);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't really know what the problem is?

Comment: @  Jonas W. -- first when i fill text into input `id="one"` then input `id="two"` will change value. it's ok ?

Comment: When input `id="two"` change i want to alert value in input `id="two"` too.

Comment: By not change code in function `test_1_fn()` how can i do ?

Comment: *I want to alert value in input `id="two"`* : I don't understand what that means. `alert()` opens a popup message, it cannot be *"in"* an `input`.

Answer (score 0):

The best method would be probably a [MutationObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom) as changing an elements property via javascript does not trigger any events on the element. However as thats quite complicated the noobish method would be:

```
var before, el = document.getElementById("two");
setInterval(function(){
  if(before && el.value != before){
    alert(el.value);
  }
  before = el.value;
}, 50);
```

However i still don't get why youre not simply doing:

```
document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("keyup", function(){
 alert(this.value);
});
```

Comment: It's ok ? 

if i use 

`<script>
window.onkeyup = keyup;
function keyup(e) {
 var two_val = document.getElementById("two").value;
  alert(two_val);
}
</script>`